# It is possible to call kernel with this ASM bootloader? How?

Tags: assembly, x86, kernel, bootloader, osdev

I made a little bootloader. Now I want to load the C++ kernel. Can I use my little bootloader for this?

```
   [BITS 16]
   [ORG 0x7C00]
   [extern _start_kernel]

   MOV SI, LoadString
   CALL String
   CALL _start_kernel




   JMP $ 

   Print:
   MOV AH, 0x0E
   MOV BH, 0x00
   MOV BL, 0x07


   INT 0x10
   RET

   String:
   characters:
   MOV AL, [SI]
   INC SI
   OR AL, AL
   JZ stopPrint
   CALL Print
   JMP characters
   stopPrint
   RET


   LoadString db 'Loading...', 0


   TIMES 510 - ($ - $$) db 0
   DW 0xAA55
```

This is very simple bootloader and this is first time when i make bootloader(with tutorial). I use NASM in windows to compile asm code.

Comment: Not real to answer on this question, because it is very vague. Write more concrete what do you want to do... Now, you can get only `Yes` or `No` answer on your current question and it is very vague too :) Where from do you want to load you kernel? raw device? fs type? did you prepare place for this? bss/heap? and etc... Actually your question raises more questions

Comment: Among the other issues brought up, which C++ compiler are you using? is it generating 16-bit code? If it isn't then your bootloader will also have to concern itself with putting the processor into 32-bit protected mode before even attempting to execute 32-bit code. You might have an easier time of this if you use a Multiboot compliant bootloader like _GRUB_ which handles that kind of drudgery for you.

Comment: Do you have a `linker.ld` file? You need to link the Assembly code with your boot loader, otherwise, you can't call any functions within your kernel file.

Comment: @Razor Given how many times I've had rollback your edits because they make the post worse, twice for this post alone now, I wouldn't call you a perfectionist.

Answer (score 2):

> Now i want to load c++ kernel. Can i use my little asm bootloader for this?

**Not** with the code that you've written because in a bootloader it is *your* responsability to actually bring the kernel file into memory. Just declaring an external label `[extern _start_kernel]` won't do any good.
Search the forum and you will find examples that manage this.

A note on your efforts so far.
Because you wrote `[ORG 0x7C00]` you want your addresses to be relative to linear address 0. Here also it is *your* responsability to make sure that the segment registers are setup accordingly. You need to add to your code:

```
xor ax, ax
mov ds, ax
MOV SI, LoadString
```

Comment: As posted `_start_kernel` is an extern, which would imply that the `_start_kernel` routine is linked with the boot loader. In which case it wouldn't be necessary to read in the kernel. However there are several caveats to that: 1) that's not how bootloaders are typically implemented - usually they do read in the kernel 2) the BIOS will only read 1 sector during boot, so the bootloader and the _start_kernel routine would have to fit into a single sector. Even with a native 4K sector drive that won't be much of a kernel.

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to call an external function inside your kernel, you need to first have it declared in your kernel file and then call it from your bootloader. You will also need a linker file that links the kernel to the bootloader all into a seperate binary file that can then be booted using GRUB. Visit [this](http://wiki.osdev.org/Bare_Bones) site which shows you how to make your bootloader start executing from the kernel and then linking it using a linker file. You may need to have [GCC](http://wiki.osdev.org/GCC_Cross-Compiler) cross-compiler if you have linux and if you are planning to use the code on that site.